# column "i" does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was created a trigger on my table.When insert/update/delete its adds a key i,u,d like that.
And i'm trying to insert this keys on another table but gives me error like that:

```
    ERROR:  column "i" does not exist
    LINE 1: ...(operation,stamp,userid,empname,salary) VALUES('||i||', now(...
                                                                 ^
    QUERY:  SELECT dblink_exec('INSERT INTO emp_audit(operation,stamp,userid,empname,salary) VALUES('||i||', now(), user,NEW.*)')
    CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function process_emp_audit() line 14 at PERFORM


    ********** Error **********

    ERROR: column "i" does not exist
    SQL state: 42703
    Context: PL/pgSQL function process_emp_audit() line 14 at PERFORM
```

i don't know why it's give me this error.And this is my trigger function

```
-- Function: process_emp_audit()

-- DROP FUNCTION process_emp_audit();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_emp_audit()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
    PERFORM dblink_connect('dbname=ekders port=5432 user=****** password=*****');

        IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
        PERFORM dblink_exec('INSERT INTO emp_audit "D", now(), user, OLD.*;');
        PERFORM dblink_disconnect();
        RETURN OLD;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
        PERFORM dblink_exec('INSERT INTO emp_audit "U", now(), user, NEW.*;');
        PERFORM dblink_disconnect();
        RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        PERFORM dblink_exec('INSERT INTO emp_audit(operation,stamp,userid,empname,salary) VALUES('||i||', now(), user,NEW.*)');
        PERFORM dblink_disconnect();
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION process_emp_audit()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: `i` is defined nowhere...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is attempting to concatenate a value `i`, which doesn't exist, to the string. I suspect what you really wanted to do was escape the single quotes. The below should work:

```
PERFORM dblink_exec('INSERT INTO emp_audit(operation,stamp,userid,empname,salary) VALUES(''i'', now(), user,NEW.*)');
```

Comment: +1, and the same for the other queries, which currently use double quotes `"` rather than two single quotes `''`.

Comment: Thanks so much! But i have a another problem now.When i try to add something like that: insert into emp(empname,salary) VALUES('testdata',10); it's gives me column testdata does not exists.How can i fix this ? Thanks...

Comment: I would have to see the code, but I suspect its exactly the same problem.

Comment: There is http://notes.io/kdq  When i try to insert into emp(empname,salary) VALUES('testdata',10); still gives me a column testdata does not exist.